# Does react-virtualized work with airbnb/enzyme?

Tags: react-virtualized

Is it possible to use react-virtualized and enzyme together? When I try to use them together I seem to get an empty list of items in the grid.

Comment: Are you confident that you're passing a width and height > 0 to the Grid? (Any chance you could share some code?)

Comment: Let me make a simplified example.

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm using Autosizer. Will keep investigating...

Comment: No problem. I'll add an "answer" so I can format some example code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2 should work together, yes. I believe the likely problem is that the react-virtualized component is being given a width or height of 0 which causes it not to render anything. (It only renders enough to fill the "window" it has.)

Assuming you're using the AutoSizer HOC- (most people do)- then one pattern I've found helpful is to export 2 versions of components- one that expects explicit width/height properties and one that wraps the other with an AutoSizer. Pseudo code would be:

```
import { AutoSizer, VirtualScroll } from 'react-virtualized'

// Use this component for testing purposes so you can explicitly set width/height
export function MyComponent ({
  height,
  width,
  ...otherProps
}) {
  return (
    <VirtualScroll
      height={height}
      width={width}
      {...otherProps}
    />
  )
}

// Use this component in your browser where auto-sizing behavior is desired
export default function MyAutoSizedComponent (props) {
  return (
    <AutoSizer>
      ({ height, width }) => (
        <MyComponent
          height={height}
          width={width}
          {...props}
        />
      )
    </AutoSizer>
  )
}
```

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention. I'm using enzyme in node.js using jsdom. Does AutoSizer rely on the real DOM measurement apis?

Comment: It depends on `getBoundingClientRect` and `getComputedStyle`. You can see how it measures things here: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/AutoSizer/AutoSizer.js#L93

Comment: Ok great then your recommendation of bypassing AutoResizer is the best one since getBoundingClientRect isn't accurate in jsdom.

Comment: Shouldn't you pass `height` and `width` (the parameters of AutoSizer render callback) to MyComponent?

Comment: Yeah. Example was just written quickly as a sketch. I updated it.

Comment: You are a life saver! <3

Answer (score 4):

as of react-virtualized 9.12.0 the Autosizer has `defaultWidth` and `defaultHeight` properties.
I found setting those meant enzyme tests ran correctly - rendering the child rows as expected.

```
<AutoSizer disableHeight defaultWidth={100}>
    {({ width }) => (
  ....
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I couldn't figure out why `console.log(wrapper.debug());` wasn't showing any data for rows - only the headers were being shown.

Answer (score 2):

Putting this in my test case worked for me:

```js
import { AutoSizer } from 'react-virtualized';

// ...

it('should do something', function() {
    spyOn(AutoSizer.prototype, 'render').and.callFake(function render() {
        return (
            <div ref={this._setRef}>
                {this.props.children({ width: 200, height: 100 })}
            </div>
        );
    });

    // do something...
```

I use Jasmine's spyOn here, but other libraries have their own ways of overwriting functions.
Keep in mind that this is pretty fragile against future changes to the react-virtualized library (`this._setRef` was just yanked from the source code), and may give you false positives.

Comment: Did this with jest like this: `jest.mock('react-virtualized-auto-sizer', () => {
  return mockAutoSizer;
});` where mockAutoSizer is the function you just described.